# Unable to boot because of Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, bbswitch

I have Nvidia Tesla K20 GPU to use for Tensorflow. When I install Nvidia driver version 375 or 384, after restart it shows

```
. bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
. bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
. bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
. bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
. bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
............... indefinitely .......
```

I use recovery mode to uninstall driver and everything goes back to normal. Same thing happens for both Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04.

If I use command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

it installs driver version 304 and it works but Tensorflow requires CUDA 8.0 and it requires driver version at least 361. Any driver newer than version 304 causes the same problem.